# transaction report with Item name & Buyer email

Tags: javascript, paypal

Is there a way to generate a PayPal report which includes both Item name (or ID) and buyer email?
Solution can be either via google script or directly via PayPal report engine

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PayPal account reporting center has many reports. You can use PayPal Activity Download report for getting both item name, buyer email address in one report.